# How can I deploy Django Gunicorn under Apache proxy?

Tags: python, django, apache, deployment, gunicorn

I've run through the documentation and am hitting the same pages over and over again. At present I've found documentation to run off an existing myapp.wsgi file, but documentation for how to make an appropriate wsgi file is a little harder to find.

If I want to make, proxied by Apache, the equivalent of, on an older version of Gunicorn etc.:

```
python manage.py run_gunicorn 0.0.0.0:8888
```

what should I be doing to supply a WSGI file for:

```
gunicorn project.wsgi:application
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you need a special wsgi file? You just use exactly the same one you would use for any other deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're not asking about the content of the wsgi file (which is often pretty standard) but how to assemble a gunicorn command line that allows gunicorn to find/use the wsgi file for your project?

When deploying to a staging server, I recall having a problem getting the Python path set so that gunicorn could find the proper wsgi file for my app. Here is a trimmed version of the gunicorn command that I ended up using:

```
gunicorn --pythonpath /some_path/my_app/my_app my_app.wsgi:application
```

In plain English, starting from the right and working backward:

- There is a function named `application` inside a the `wsgi.py` file
- The `wsgi.py` file is inside a module named `my_app` (which in this case is a directory containing a `__init__.py` file)
- The `my_app` module is located at `/some_path/my_app/my_app`, so this needs to be on the PYTHONPATH.

So the full path to your `wsgi.py` is:

`/some_path/my_app/my_app/my_app/wsgi.py`.

In the same directory as `wsgi.py` is a `__init__.py` file, which causes Python to recognize that directory as a module.